# Put the json array into hashmap using java

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

```
{
    "Servers": [
        {
            "server": "server1",
            "port": "8000"
        },
        {
            "server": "server2",
            "port": "8000"
        },
        {
            "server": "server3",
            "port": "8000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to put this json file into a HashMap using:

```
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonfile, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

`jsonfile` here indicates the path in which the json file is stored.
Please suggest how should I put this json file into a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

The easy and maintainable solution would be to use one of JSON parsing libraries such as [GSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

In general you'll have to create bean object which will define structure of json file, and then you can parse it like this

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));

    //convert the json string back to object
    DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Gson as well.

Import it into your project(build.gradle of your app) if you're using Gradle as;

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

*If you're not using Gradle, see [Gson docs here](https://github.com/google/gson) for other build tools.*

Create a container object to parse your Json into and hold your values;

```
class Server {
    String server;
    int port;
    // I did not take encapsulation into account for brevity
}
```

Then use Gson to parse your Server objects as list;

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path_to_your_file"));
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Server> serverList = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<List<Server>>(){}.getType());
```

serverList will be containing a list of your Server objects.